# Почему нажатие на окно-заставку приводит к тому, что это окно пропадает?(Python, PyQt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qsplashscreen

У меня есть код на Python для отображения окна-заставки, которое выводит изображение и процент загрузки. Нажатие на это окно приводит к его исчезновению. Почему это происходит? Как мне сделать так, чтобы окно не реагировало на нажатия?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time, sys

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QPushButton.__init__(self)
        self.setText("Закрыть окно")
        self.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)
    def load_data(self, sp):
        for i in range(1, 11):
            time.sleep(0.2)
            sp.showMessage("Загрузка данных... {0}%".format(i * 10),
                           QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.black)
            QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("aaa.png"))
    splash.showMessage("Загрузка данных... 0%", 
                       QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.black)
    splash.show()
    QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Window")
    window.resize(400, 60)
    window.load_data(splash)
    window.show()
    splash.finish(window)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина в том, что [это прописано в стандартной логике](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qsplashscreen.cpp?h=dev#n189), что мне кажется очень странным:

```cpp
void QSplashScreen::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    hide();
}
```

Предлагаю сделать своего наследника от [QSplashScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html) и убрать обработку события `mousePressEvent`:

```
...

class SplashScreen(QtWidgets.QSplashScreen):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    splash = SplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("aaa.png"))
    splash.showMessage("Загрузка данных... 0%",
                       QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.black)
    splash.show()
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я понял свою ошибку:)

Comment: @MAXIM045, пожалуйста и нет тут вашей ошибки :)